# Infinite date column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I saw an Excel spreadsheet once that had a date column that would span a couple of month down and that would be the end of the spreadsheet, but every day you open and use it, that date at the bottom would add and the date at the top would disappear, so basically you have an "infinite" spreadsheet that automatically moves forward with time as you use it every day. I struggle finding the solution for this on the net, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Have a great day everyone!

Comment: What have you tried yourself beside searching the internet?

Comment: You can enter `=TODAY()+ROW()-1` in a cell and fill it down. It'll automatically update every day.

Comment: I don't even have a clue where to start, all I did was filling up the column with dates (by using autofill). But it is static, and I will have to expand it when I reach the end of the sheet. And the earlier parts are gonna stay in place, so the file will grow larger by each day.

Comment: For example the start date is 2021-6-1 and the end date is Today, the next day I open the Excel the end date will add to next cell 2021-7-1 and 2021-6-1 will removed from first cell? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Lee, yes, but the whole row with the 2021-6-1 should be removed. So with time all the old data disappears and the date just moves forward.

Comment: If you want to use this table to store your data and one row of data gets deleted with a new one added every day, that sounds like a VBA macro that runs when you open the file. If you have lots of data stored somewhere else and you want to extract a portion of that data for viewing in a separate sheet, then that viewing sheet could be all formulas. Which are you going for here? (It's often helpful to mockup exactly what you want and share the screenshots.)